# Background image cutting off part of text in Javascript?

Tags: html, css, text

I have a simple background image, on which I am overlaying text. However, the first portion of the text, which is bolded, is cut off by the image, as shown below.
I have tried removing the `<strong>` tag, but to no avail. I also added the `z-index` property, thinking that the image was overlaying the text, which also yielded no result.

What do I need to do to prevent my text from being invisible?

```css
.image {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/23049/pexels-photo.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index:0;
}
#faded {
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-left: 7px;
}
#large {
  font-size: 55px;
  display:inline-block;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>

<div class="title">
    <p class="titleText">
        <span id="large"><strong>We aspire</strong></span>
        <span id="faded">to match individuals with the jobs they need</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Image of result:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `position: relative;` to `#large` container

See snippet below

```css
.image {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQI0475wfDXQzGz3vS0MvnUcYgj3Do5YBW2Uf19mEpm-pngoM_E);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index:0;
  background-size:cover;
}

#faded {
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-left: 7px;
}

#large {
  font-size: 55px;
  display:inline-block;
  z-index:1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>

<div class="title">
    <p class="titleText">
        <span id="large"><strong>We aspire</strong></span>
        <span id="faded">to match individuals with the jobs they need</span>
    </p>
</div>
```